# Exclude child comments in get_comments() or WP_Comment_Query?

Tags: comments, query, wp-comment-query

How do I only get the first level of comments in get_comments() or WP_Comment_Query?
I want to query the comments which have 'comment_parent' => 0, and exclude all the child comments.

```
    $args = array(
        'number'      => 10,
        'order'       => 'DESC',
        'status'      => 'approve',
        'meta_key'    => 'comment_parent',
        'meta_value'  => 0
    );

    $comments = get_comments( $args );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick, I guess:

```
$args = array(
    'number'      => 10,
    'order'       => 'DESC',
    'status'      => 'approve',
    'parent'      => 0
);

$comments = get_comments( $args );
```

You can find full list of arguments in [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments).

Comment: Yes - and as all of such WP functions, if you pass 0 as parent, it means to get only first level objects (without parent)